# Problems wih Eclipse / Spring Boot / Camunda

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, camunda, gradle-eclipse

we are working on a project that uses spring boot, camunda, gradle. we are using  Eclipse as IDE. When we start the app in the run mode, everything works fine. Not so in debug mode. During start up the app crashes because camunda / spring says that some objects are added twice to the application context. This happens as well when we enable spring dev tools. The classpath is printed out to the console when stating. That shows that the project root is part of it. Maybe scanning the root folder and the classes folder to create the application context causes the problem. 
Starting the app from within gradle does not produce this error. Also if we use IntelliJ instead of Eclipse we do not run into this error.

Any tips appreciased

TIA Kibu

Answer (score 0):

Solved with eclipse Photon (4.9)

Kibu